# OpenLayers displays nothing when I try to add WFS Layer from Geoserver - can't work out where the problem is occurring!

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wfs

I hope someone can help me with this problem as I'm very confused!

I recently downloaded the IHO Sea Areas shape file from http://www.marineregions.org/downloads.php

One of my colleagues has uploaded the shape file to PostGIS and served it up using Geoserver. Because I want to display it over a google maps base layer in OpenLayers, we tried to set Geoserver to "Reproject Native to Declared" from **EPSG:4326** (detected by Geoserver) to **EPSG:3857** (Google projection). However, when trying to access the layer through Geoserver, I got a **404 The requested resource () is not available**.

The only way that Geoserver would serve the file was if we set it to "Force Declared", at which point the WFS would return the data as requested.

So, I don't really understand why that's the case, but I got a WFS that seemed to work.

Next step (note: I have set up OpenLayers with a declared projection of EPSG:3857 on the map), I added the layer to OpenLayers using:

```
IHO = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("IHO Areas",{ 
            style: {
                    strokeColor: "green",
                    strokeWidth: 1,
                    fillColor: "green",
                    fillOpacity: "0.2",
                    cursor: "pointer"
                },
                projection: "EPSG:3857",
                strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
                protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                    url: "http://*MyWebProxy*/IHO_Areas.php",
                    format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
                })
            }); 

    IHO.events.on({"loadend":function(){console.log(this);}});  
    map.addLayers([IHO]);
```

Now, the "loadend" event successfully fires, the logged IHO layer shows that it, and all its features, have been fetched successfully and the projection is logged as EPSG:3857 on the layer object, no errors are thrown by javascript/OpenLayers. But, nothing appears on the map.

This is especially weird as I copied and pasted the code from one of my earlier projects that worked perfectly using a different WFS vector layer source. So it seems there must be something weird about the IHO shape file or the data extracted from it, but I don't really know what to look for to fix it. Can anyone suggest anything to help?